# How to display Markov Chain plots in Rstudio (markovchain package)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu-12.04, rstudio, markov-chains

Latest Rstudio and latest R ( in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 - 32bit ).

Most plots will display OK in my Rstudio [Plots] pane.
But some Markov Chain plots throw an Error and don't display.

Here's a very simple example code:

```
library(markovchain) #loading the package
myMatr<-matrix(c(0,.2,.8,.1,.8,.1,.3,0,.7),byrow=TRUE,nrow = 3)     
## defining a transition matrix
rownames(myMatr)<-colnames(myMatr)<-c("a","b","c")
myMc<-as(myMatr, "markovchain")

plot(myMc)  # <== Error message starts after this...
```

gives this Rstudio Console Error:
(and no plot is displayed in Rstudio)

```
"Error in cut.default(x, binsToUse, labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE,  : 'x' must be numeric"
```

Yet, exactly the same R commands (as above)
*work fine* in "stand-alone" R 3.2.3! (outside of Rstudio).
And the Markov Chain plot is displayed ok in a new R-window...

Q:
- Is there an easy way/command to tell Rstudio 
that I want certain plots 
to open in a new R window (just like in pure R),
and NOT in the Rstudio Plot pane?
- Or some other easy solution?

Comment: It does work on my setup with RStudio Version 0.99.465 on windows

Comment: Hmm...Rstudio 0.99.878 here. Are you in Linux? Apparently, Rstudio has this problem displaying some plots and solution (which I don't know) is different for Windows, Mac and Linux...

Comment: RStudio 0.99878 and R 3.2.3 work. Could you give your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: (1) is sessionInfo() the same in your standalone R session and within RStudio? Or might you be picking up different R/package versions? (2) it will probably be more convenient to edit the `sessionInfo()` results into your question, rather than dumping them in comments (probably OK to redact the locale information, it's unlikely to be relevant) (3) the answer to your last question is `?x11`

Comment: Thanks Ben! How exactly do I use x11 inRstudio,
to plot to a new window (outside Rstudio). 
Could  you pls give a quick code example? 
Do I do > x11() and then 
> plot(myMc) ? thanks!

Comment: >x11 and then >plot(something...) works, EXCEPT to plot() a Markov Chain object (in my Rstudio, at least).  So I finally decided to use plotmat(myMC) from Rstudio.  plotmat() will plot the Markov Chain network just fine in Rstudio!  Thanks for your persistence & patience, Ben Bolker! Have a super-great day, Ben!